# Catch exceptions with custom messages via BEGIN CATCH in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to implement T-SQL try catch in  SQL Server management studio. Here is my Code:

```
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
 alter table [SalesLT].[ProductModel]
 add testtimestamp123 timestamp 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('MY CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSAGE',16,1)
END CATCH
END;
```

My expectation is, that I receive my Custom message if I run this code in sql server management studio (because I have a column with timestamp datatype in this table) but I recieve this message:
*`A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table 'ProductModel' already has one, the column 'testtimestamp123' cannot be added.`*

What should I do to catch my exceptions with custom messages?

Comment: Side note, `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym of `rowversion`; you shouldn't really be using `timestamp` any more.

Comment: You certainly cannot use code like this (if it worked) for general purposes. You catch every error and then attempt to throw a specific one - which might be completely unrelated to the error you caught. Seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And if you're going to use statement terminators - which you should - you should use them consistently for every statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert that sql statement into dynamic SQL then the error will be thrown at the point of execution rather than when parsed. E.g. something like this

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'alter table demo add testtimestamp123 timestamp ';
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('MY CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSAGE',16,1)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all exceptions in T-SQL can be "caught". This is one of them.

If you don't want to use a "dynamic" statemnt, you could an `EXISTS` against the `sys` objects and then you can `THROW` your custom error if the column already exists:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (Id int,
                            rowversion rowversion); --Don't use timestamp, it's deprecated

GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM sys.schemas s
                    JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
               WHERE s.name = N'dbo'
                 AND t.name = N'SomeTable'
                 AND c.name = N'rowversion')
    ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD rowversion rowversion;
ELSE
    THROW 65762, N'A column of the name you want to create already exists. I can''t do this. Sorry :(', 10;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```